# AngularJS Property Bag

Tags: angularjs

Is there a formal property bag for Angular?  I need a way to temporarily store variables and optionally save them between apps.

Comment: This would read slightly better as a self-answered question.  You can phrase your question as you would normally ( it does need more detail though ), then answer with your custom property bag.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about doing that, but I didn't want anyone to skip the question with it already being answered.  I'm more interested in finding a formal solution.

Answer (score 1):

To save time, I whipped one up.  It's here if anyone needs it, however I would love to find one in a framework that is supported by a team:

```
/**
 * Created by Fred Lackey on 4/24/15.
 */
(function (module) {

    var propertyBag = function (localStorage) {

        var items = [];

        var getIndex = function (key) {
            if (!key || !key.trim || key.trim().length < 1) { return -1; }
            if (items.length < 1) { return -1; }
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1) {
                if (items[i].key.toLowerCase() === key.toLowerCase()) { return i; }
            }
            return -1;
        };
        var exists = function (key) {
            return (getIndex(key) >= 0);
        };

        var getItem = function (key) {
            var index = getIndex(key);
            return (index >= 0) ? items[index] : null;
        };
        var getValue = function (key) {
            var index = getIndex(key);
            return (index >= 0) ? items[index].value : null;
        };
        var putItem = function (key, value) {
            if (!key || !key.trim || key.trim().length < 1) { return; }
            var index = getIndex(key);
            if (index >= 0) {
                items[index].value = value;
            } else {
                items.push({ key: key, value: value });
            }
        };
        var removeItem = function (key) {
            var index = getIndex(key);
            if (index >= 0) { items.splice(index, 1); }
        };
        var count = function () {
            return items.length;
        };

        var saveBag = function (key) {
            if (!key || !key.trim || key.trim().length < 1) { return; }
            localStorage.add(key, items);
        };

        var loadBag = function (key) {
            if (!key || !key.trim || key.trim().length < 1) { return; }
            var bag = localStorage.get(key);
            if (!bag || !bag.length) { return; }
            for (var i = 0; i < bag.length; b += 1) {
                if (!bag[i].key || !bag[i].key.trim || bag[i].key.trim().length < 1) { continue; }
                putItem(bag[i].key, bag[i].value);
            }
            localStorage.remove(key);
        };

        return {
            getItem: getItem,
            exists: exists,
            getValue: getValue,
            putItem: putItem,
            removeItem: removeItem,
            count: count,
            save: saveBag,
            load: loadBag
        };
    };

    module.factory('propertyBag', propertyBag);

})(angular.module('common'));
```

Here's the local storage code if you don't already have one (referenced in the code above)...

```
(function (module) {

    var localStorage = function ($window) {

        var store = $window.localStorage;

        var add = function (key, value) {
            value = angular.toJson(value);
            store.setItem(key, value);
        };

        var get = function (key) {
            var value = store.getItem(key);
            if (value) {
                value = angular.fromJson(value);
            }
            return value;
        };

        var remove = function (key) {
            store.removeItem(key);
        };

        return {
            add: add,
            get: get,
            remove: remove
        }

    };

    module.factory('localStorage', localStorage);

})(angular.module('common'));
```